# How to pass JSON content to another JSON file

Tags: python, json

**file1.json**

```
[
  {
    "username": "Jack"
  },
  {
    "username": "Harry"
  }
]
```

I want to fetch only username as ['Jack', 'Harry'] and replace in other json file using python.

**file2.json**

```
{
  "profile":
  [
    {
      "custom_data": 
        {
          "env.user_data": "fetch_name"
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

So as final output in **file2.json** `"env.user_data": ['Jack', 'Harry']`

Below is the code I am using to read the file.

```
import json
def name():
    contents= []

    try:
        with open("file1.json", 'r') as f:
            contents = json.load(f)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    data = [item.get('username') for item in contents]
    return data   

test=name()
print(test)
```

Comment: Did you forget to paste the code you used to try this?

Comment: The answer would be the same, regardless of what Python version you use, but you really shouldnt be using Python2

Comment: I give -1 for not tagging python 2 explicitly

Comment: @rv It was. I removed it. Tag should not be used unless it's a version specific question

Comment: I see the post has been updated since last. In that case, I retract my downvote. However, just a note that this question isn't specific to one version (Python 2); otherwise, all seems good to me.

Comment: Can you help in regards to solution . @rv.kvetch

Comment: Hmm.. what's wrong? seems like the solution should work for your case.

Comment: This solution works when its dumping the 1st data ,but now working if have nested JSON data. @rv.kvetch

Comment: @ansh1 I would suggest opening another question, but this time stating the problem more **clearly**. It looks like this is a completely different problem; the answer below works for the use case outlined in the question, and you should accept it if that is the case. Whether it works for nested JSON data is a separate question, as this was not mentioned in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Unclear what you expect to happen when there is more than one `profile` element (shouldn't each user have their own profile?)

But if you want to just replace one element, then that would look like this

```
import json 

with open('file1.json') as f1, open('file2.json') as f2:
  j1 = json.load(f1)
  j2 = json.load(f2)

names = [d['username'] for d in j1]
j2['profile'][0]['custom_data']['env.user_data'] = names

with open('file2.json', 'w') as f:
  json.dump(j2, f)
```

Comment: How to find and fetch data if we have multiple data in JSON. Example: { "profile":[
        {  
          "id":"4",
          "group":"D"
        },
        {  
          "id":"5",
          "age":"46"
        },
        {  
          "id":"6",
          "custom_data": 
            {
              **"env.user_data": "fetch_name"**
            }
        }
      ]
    } @OneCricketeer

Comment: It should fetch the **"env.user_data": "fetch_name"** irrespective of position its placed. @OneCricketeer

Comment: I suggest taking more time to learn to parse json, but try `[p.get("custom_data') for p in j2["profile"]]`

Comment: Can You Please update in code .Thanks ins advance for the effort . @OneCricketeer

Comment: That wasn't part of your original question, though

Comment: Yes , But when using this **j2['profile'][0]['custom_data']['env.user_data'] = names**
Its work for when it is 1st data , please update in regards to convert this line in loop

Comment: Edit your question to show what you expect